# Send and Receive JSON using RestClient and Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rest-client

I am trying to send a JSON data to a Sinatra app by RestClient ruby API.

At client(client.rb) (using RestClient API)

```
response = RestClient.post 'http://localhost:4567/solve', jdata, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json
```

At server (Sinatra)

```
require "rubygems"
require "sinatra"


post '/solve/:data' do 

  jdata = params[:data]

  for_json = JSON.parse(jdata)

end
```

I get the following error

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.5.1/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:53:in `return!': Resource Not Found (RestClient::ResourceNotFound)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.5.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:193:in `process_result'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.5.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:142:in `transmit'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:543:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.5.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:139:in `transmit'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.5.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:56:in `execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.5.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:31:in `execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.5.1/lib/restclient.rb:72:in `post'
    from client.rb:52
```

All I want is to send JSON data and receive a JSON data back using RestClient and Sinatra..but whatever I try, I get the above error. I m stuck with this for 3 hours. Please help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your sinatra app, don't match with http://localhost:4567/solve URL, so it's return a 404 from your server.

You need change your sinatra app by example :

```
require "rubygems"
require "sinatra"


post '/solve/?' do 
  jdata = params[:data]
  for_json = JSON.parse(jdata)
end
```

You have a problem with your RestClient request too. You need define the params name of jdata.

```
response = RestClient.post 'http://localhost:4567/solve', {:data => jdata}, {:content_type => :json, :accept => :json}
```

Comment: i didnt restart my sintara server.. thats the prob.. ;) your code worked like sweet

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jdata = {:key => 'I am a value'}.to_json    
response = RestClient.post 'http://localhost:4567/solve', :data => jdata, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json
```

And then try this:

```
post '/solve' do 
  jdata = JSON.parse(params[:data])
  puts jdata
end
```

I didn't test it but maybe you should send the json data as value rather than a key. Is is possible that you data looks like this: {:key => 'I am a value'} => nil. Your data does not necessary has to be in url at all. You don't  need /solve/:data url. POST values are not to be send in url
A good way to debug what you receive in your route is to print the params:

```
puts params
```

Hope this helps!